# Laravel Eloquent One-To-Many

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel and I'm trying to make a simple CMS system. 
I made the following models which are one-to-many related:

**Page** (id, name, blocks)

```
public function blocks() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Block');
}
```

**Block** (id, name, displayName, content)

```
public function page() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Page');
}
```

Now I want to create a page and set the blocks right away.
I'm getting a `$request` object looking like this:

```
{ 
   "name": "Page name",
   "blocks": [
      {
         "name": "block name",
         "displayName": "Display Name",
         "content": "Some HTML content"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now, I'm trying to save these all to the database, but I'm running in a lot of errors.

So far, I concluded I have to iterate over every 'block' and actually create a new `Block`. But I'm not exactly sure how to save it to the database.

Do I save the page first, then add the Blocks or first the blocks and then the page. I'm getting a bit confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure you have a `page_id` column in the blocks table and the foreign key constraint like this :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('blocks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        // your fields here
        $table->integer('page_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('page_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('pages')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Second, you have to save the page first to the database, and then add to blocks to the page. Because you need the page_id when you create the blocks.

Finally,

> You may use the `createMany` method to create multiple related models.
>   [See Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method)

Example:

```
$page = App\Page::create([
    'name' => 'name',
]);

$blocks = $page->blocks()->createMany([
    [
        'name' => 'name1',
        'displayName' => 'displayName1',
        'content' => 'content1'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'name2',
        'displayName' => 'displayName2',
        'content' => 'content2'
    ],
]);

// to get all blocks from the request
$blocks = $page->blocks()->createMany(request('blocks'));
```

Comment: As the `$request` instance exists within the scope, `$request->get('blocks')` is preferred over using the helper.

Comment: Working like a charm. Used your solution to get blocks from request, didn't know there was a function createMany(). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [createMany](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method) method. Do it like this. You can refer [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method).

```
$page = Page::create($request->only('name'));

$page->blocks()->createMany($request->get('blocks'));
```